CockroachDB row level locks wont allow granting locks on non-conflicting rows
I was trying to create the locking feature of a booking applicaion using node, react and postgres so i used cockroachDB. But cockroach db seems to not allow granting locks on non-conflicting rows.
this is the api endpoint that i created:
I am using 'pg' library for connecting my app with database.
app.patch("/book", async (req, res) => {
  const slots = req.body;

  const queryString = slots.join(",");

 const query = `select * from bookings where id in ($1) FOR UPDATE`;

  const dbQuery = query.replace("$1", queryString);

  console.log(dbQuery);

  try {
    await client.query("BEGIN");

    const bookings = await client.query(dbQuery);

    console.log(bookings.rows);

    if (!bookings.rows) {
      console.log("TX rolled back");
      await client.query("ROLLBACK");
    }

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

    await client.query("COMMIT");
    console.log("TX commited to the db");
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      message: "slots booked",
      data: bookings.rows,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "failure",
      error: new Error(error).message,
    });
  }
});

Now if user A wants to lock row with id 1 and 2 then it is granted but if user B tries to lock row 3 (basically any row other than 1 and 2) then i get an error saying
error: there is already a transaction in progress
But as per row-level locks this error should not occur right? because it does not affect non-conflicting rows.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am just a beginner trying to learn about locks.
I just want to know if this is from cockroachDB's side or my code needs some changes. Also i tried this locks feature with the pgadmin local database but locks does not seem to work at all for local database. Any advice on how to perform locks on local database with node js and pg library
